# getting response still unable to update an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

```
HTML(dynamically added table):    
<td>
    <input type = "textbox" name = "Adj_qty[]" size = "3%" class = "form-control Adj_qty" id ="up_Adj_qty"
</td>
<td>
    <input type = "checkbox" value = "" name = "ms_confrim_qty[]"class ="ms_confrim_qty" id = "ms_confrim_qty">
</td>
<td style = "display:none">
    <input type = "textbox" value = '+b.id+' name = "indent_autoid[] " class = "indent_autoid" id = "up_indent_autoid">
</td>
 <button  type="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
```

controller:

```
public function approval_qty()
{
    $appr_qty = array();
    $indentserial_id = $this->input->post('indent_autoid');
    $appr_qty['approval_qty'] = $this->input->post('Adj_qty');
    $this->outpatient_model->update_row('tra_indent_item_dt',array('id'=>$this->input->post('indent_autoid')),$appr_qty);

    $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode(array("response" => 'updated')));
    }
```

js:

```
var up_qty = {
        ajax: 1,
        up_array :[],
        up_array['id'] : $('#up_indent_autoid').val(),
        up_array['Adj_qty'] : $('#up_Adj_qty').val(), }

var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
$.ajax({
    url:  base_url+"/indent_approval/approval_qty",
    type: 'POST',
    data: stringify(up_qty),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Updated Successfully");
        location.reload(); 
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error.');
    }
});
```

Trying to update an array.
how to pass an array when type = submit /button.
getting response still unable to update an array help me to update.

when i tried execute this getting an array,when i do same for without array i can post data still unable to update

now am getting an error msg like:
missing:after propertity id

Answer (score 0):

your click button event should look like this assuming your dynamic code is wrap in a `tr` tag

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var up_qty = {
                        ajax: 1,
                        indent_autoid : $(this).parent('tr').find('#up_indent_autoid').val(),
                        Adj_qty : $(this).parent('tr').find('#up_Adj_qty').val(),

                        }
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
    $.ajax({
        url:  base_url+"/indent_approval/approval_qty",
        type: 'POST',
        data: up_qty,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Updated Successfully");
            location.reload(); 
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error.');
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: i tried this:var up_qty = {
                ajax: 1,
                id : $('#up_indent_autoid').val(),
                Adj_qty : $('#up_Adj_qty').val(),

                } am getting response unable to update in db

Comment: change this `$this->input->post('indent_autoid')` to `$this->input->post('id')`

Comment: or `id : $('#up_indent_autoid').val(),` to `indent_autoid : $('#up_indent_autoid').val(),`

Comment: yeah i changed  still no luck..getting an error like 
uncaught exception: out of memory
 

...sout"},function(a,b){var c=function(a){m.event.simulate(b,a.target,m.event.fix(a...

Comment: getting post data.when i echo last_query getting approval_qty" = 0 WHERE "id" =  0
post:
ajax 
1
up_array[Adj_qty] 
34
up_array[id] 
3
responce:
UPDATE "tra_indent_item_dt" SET "approval_qty" = 0 WHERE "id" =  0{"response":"updated"}